# WildFly 9 Failed to parse service xml

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

**jboss-service.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:service:7.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:service:7.0 jboss-service_7_0.xsd">
    <mbean name="com.xxx.yyy:service=SomeClass"
        code="com.xxx.yyy.SomeClassBean"  xmbean-dd="META-INF/config-mbeans.xml" />
</server>
```

I have jboss-service.xml above and I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state START_ELEMENT is not among the statesCHARACTERS, COMMENT, CDATA, SPACE, ENTITY_REFERENCE, DTD valid for getText() 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.getText(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.getText(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:275)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.unexpectedContent(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:638)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.parseMBean(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:221)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.readElement(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:192)
    at org.jboss.as.service.descriptor.JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.readElement(JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:48)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.service.ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(ServiceDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:96)
    ... 6 more
```

Any idea how to fix this? Tried other suggestions, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try with  `<mbean  ... ></mbean>` instead  `<mbean  ... />`

Answer (score 0):

According to the section **9.6.2** of the [JBossAS docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/The_JBoss_Server___A_Quick_Tour.html), you need to define your `mbean` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:service:7.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:service:7.0 jboss-service_7_0.xsd">
    <mbean code="..." name="...">
    </mbean>
</server>
```

**EDIT**

After looking at the source code of [JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java:221](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/sar/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/service/descriptor/JBossServiceXmlDescriptorParser.java), one understands that the element `xmbean-dd` is no longer expected on Wildfly 9. Only `NAME`and `CODE` are expected.

Remove that element from your `mbean` tag and it will work.

Comment: I did try <mbean>...</mbean> but the error is still the same.

Comment: Could you please update your answer with the new `jboss-service.xml` structure?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <server xmlns="urn:jboss:service:7.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:service:7.0 jboss-service_7_0.xsd">
       <mbean name="com.xxx.yyy:service=SomeClass"
                code="com.xxx.yyy.SomeClassBean"  xmbean-dd="META-INF/config-mbeans.xml" > </mbean>
        </server>`

Comment: Please refer to my edit in order to see if it finally solves your problem.

Comment: Was this the solution?

Comment: @JoseChavez dunno... the OP never replied back. Have you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: I have to test and see. In the middle of a migration of jboss-4.2.3.GA to AWS, but meeting many blockers. Was wondering if upgrading to wildfly would help, but have many mbeans defined.